# How to remove admin submenu item of WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I installed the following plug-in  to provide testimonials for my WordPress site.

https://codecanyon.net/item/testimonials-showcase-wordpress-plugin/6588139

The plug-in somehow creates a submenu „Group“ with link „edit-tags.php&taxonomy=ttshowcase_groups&post_type=ttshowcase“ which I would like to get removed as there is no need for my case to have such groups.

So I reviewed the files on the plug-in’s directory but can’t find where the menu is created. It somehow looks to me it’s there by default or similar.

So I tried adding a function to the plugins main php file using „remove_submenu_page“, but that’s just crashing the whole site.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add to your functions.php

```
remove_menu_page( 'edit-tags.php&taxonomy=ttshowcase_groups&post_type=ttshowcase' );
```